# UK pension (SIPP) of a non-US citizen (and non-US resident) invested in US stocks - is it liable for US estate tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, non-resident, estate-planning

The title pretty much sums it up:

I am not residing in the US and I'm not a US citizen. I do have a UK pension (SIPP) which is invested in US stocks. The SIPP is held with Interactive Brokers which is US brokerage.

If I die - would my pension be liable for US Estate Tax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The United Kingdom is one of 15 rare countries who has [Estate or Gift Tax Treaty](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/estate-gift-tax-treaties-international) with the United States.

The full text is here: https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1979/1454/made/data.pdf

> **Article 8(5)**
>
> Where property may be taxed in the United States on the death of a
> United Kingdom national who was neither domiciled in nor a national of
> the United States and a claim is made under this paragraph, the tax
> imposed in the United States shall be **limited to** the amount of tax
> which **would have been** imposed **had** the decedent become domiciled in the
> United States immediately before his death, on the property which
> would in that event have been taxable.

This means that residents of United Kingdom are eligible for the **12.06 million USD exemption** from US Estate Tax, unlike other non-treaty countries where the exemption is mere 60,000 USD.

For estate amount above 12.06 million USD (prorated US:Worldwide assets), it seems that the US will provide tax credit for "tax paid in the UK" only if the assets were **held inside a Trust** (i.e. not a SIPP).

When the articles were written in 1970s, the "tax paid in the UK" only meant "UK capital transfer tax". Although Article 2(2) said "This Convention shall also apply to any **identical or substantially similar taxes** which are imposed by a Contracting State **after the date** of signature of the Convention **in addition to**, or in place of, the existing taxes". Thus it should cover UK Inheritance Tax (successor to UK Capital Transfer Tax in 1986). However, SIPPs are not subject to UK Inheritance Tax anyway.

> **Article 9(3)(c)**
>
> Where the United States imposes tax with respect to property [held in a trust] which is
> not taxable in accordance with the said Article 6 or 7 and
> sub-paragraph (b) does not apply, the United States *shall credit*
> against the tax calculated according to its law with respect to that
> property an amount equal to the tax **paid in the United Kingdom** with
> respect to that property.

Comment: SIPP are not liable for inheritance tax in the UK only if you die before reaching 75

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed post! I'm still a bit confused about the wording of Article 8(5) - it sounds like US may tax a SIPP **as if** you have become resident immediately before dying.

Comment: Yes, US may tax a SIPP as if you have become resident immediately before dying, at the same time you can enjoy the 12.06 million USD exemption, i.e. no US estate tax for SIPP.